# Two repos for the same entity, one exported and one not

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Using Sring Data JPA, Spring Data REST 2.4.2, Spring Security and Spring Boot 1.3.1. I have an Account entity that I want to expose over REST for admin purposes:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")  //exclusive admin access
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {}
```

This works as expected and I can access the REST interface with a proper admin role.

Another requirement I have is to allow non-admin users to register and authenticate over HTTP. For that I've created a custom Controller that exposes register() and login() functionality over /register and /login resources. The issue is that when the registration/login internal logic interacts with the repo above, there is no user security context that can be attached, apart from an anonymous one.

To keep things simple I have created a second repo that is not exported and has no security requirements:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface AccountRepositoryInternal extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {}
```

This repo is then then injected in the said controller.

The issue is that I see inconsistent behaviour with the exported interface. In some runtime environments the interface is exported over REST and in others it is not. Is there a better strategy I could use?

Comment: Finally... I had been pulling my hair out all morning.  I had created 2 repositoires and got weird behaviour and couldnt figure it out .  I finally searched for 2 repos and got your question.  I had setup PreAuthroize a the method level but couldnt figure out the weird behaviour I was getting until I saw that you had it as well

Comment: See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-923

Answer (score 4):

You can add `@PreAuthorize` at both class and method level, so if you need only some methods do be secured just:

1. Use only one repo instead of two
2. Extend `Repository` instead that `JPARepository`
3. Copy and paste (literally, they are just placeholders) all the methods that you need from `PagingAndSortingRepository`.
4. Add `@PreAuthorize` accordingly to your needs to specific methods, not to the class.

Copying and pasting methods among repositories interfaces is what the docs suggests (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.definition-tuning) if you want to have a fine grained control, such as in you case.

Comment: Thanks Luca but that's not really what I aim for. Such copying will add to the confusion imho.

Comment: IMHO, I don't see how having 2 repos is less confusing that having only 1 repo with the proper security configuration (evry developer should have to remember to use the correct one in different scenarios). I will also edit my answer in order to state it cleaner.

Comment: @florind & Luca Abbati **love you both** No way, I could've guessed this was my issue in the junit runs!