# Spring Data REST repository 404 from time to time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have the Spring Boot application with Spring Data REST.

I have the following classes in it:

Data JPA repository for authentication purposes:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Secured Data REST repository for API usages:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
@Secured(Role.ROLE_USER_READ)
public interface UserDataRestRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
    @Override
    @Secured(Role.ROLE_USER_WRITE)
    <S extends User>S save(S entity);

    @Override
    @Secured(Role.ROLE_USER_DELETE)
    void delete(Long id);
}
```

Repository REST configurer adapter:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(RepositoryDetectionStrategies.ANNOTATED);
        config.setReturnBodyOnCreate(true);
        config.setReturnBodyOnUpdate(true);
        config.setReturnBodyForPutAndPost(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I start up my application, Data REST repository for API is unavailable from time to time. I guess it's because Spring rewrites repository bean for type User with the first JPA repository.

In Actuator beans endpoint I can see both beans even if REST API says 404 for /users page.

Again, this behavior is unpredictable for me - sometimes it works, sometimes doesn't.

Do you know the way how to tell to Spring to use the exact bean for Data REST?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, I've found exactly the same issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520362/two-repos-for-the-same-entity-one-exported-and-one-not).

Also, see [this one](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-923).

Finally, I've merged 2 repositories into one and it solved my problem. But this is definitely not the way I prefer.

Comment: How would you implement an unsecured `save()` method? I need to change the user record during authentication, before the user is authorized.

Comment: @Arthur, we are using another names for such methods.